# Transforming one request to another using XSLT1.0 (grouping the elements)

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the requirement in which I have to transform one request to another.

below is the response I get from SAP backend.

**Input**

```
      <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header/>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <n0:YSdsaUsseedRetDetailResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <EHdr>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln>0020014747</Yyvbeln>
                    <Yyyear>2015</Yyyear>
                    <Yytext/>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln>0020014760</Yyvbeln>
                    <Yyyear>2015</Yyyear>
                    <Yytext/>
                </item>
            </EHdr>
            <EItm>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln>0020014747</Yyvbeln>
                    <Yyposnr>000010</Yyposnr>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <Yyvbeln>0020014760</Yyvbeln>
                    <Yyposnr>000020</Yyposnr>
                </item>
            </EItm>
            <EMessages/>
        </n0:YSdsaUsseedRetDetailResponse>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

**Desire output**

I have removed unwanted elements from output.

```
<mon:ReturnsList>
    <mon:ReturnProperties>
        <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
        <mon:Status>SUBMITTED</mon:Status>
        <mon:DateSubmitted>0000-00-00</mon:DateSubmitted>
        <mon:RequestedPickupDate>0000-00-00</mon:RequestedPickupDate>
        <mon:DateClosed>0000-00-00</mon:DateClosed>
        <mon:Comments/>
        <mon:PurchaseOrderNumber>36-1</mon:PurchaseOrderNumber>
        <mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
            <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
            <mon:ItemNumber>000010</mon:ItemNumber>
        </mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
    </mon:ReturnProperties>
    <mon:ReturnProperties>
        <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014760</mon:DocumentNumber>
        <mon:Status>SUBMITTED</mon:Status>
        <mon:DateSubmitted>2015-06-19</mon:DateSubmitted>
        <mon:RequestedPickupDate>2015-06-23</mon:RequestedPickupDate>
        <mon:DateClosed>0000-00-00</mon:DateClosed>
        <mon:Comments/>
        <mon:PurchaseOrderNumber/>
        <mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
            <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014760</mon:DocumentNumber>
            <mon:ItemNumber>000010</mon:ItemNumber>
        </mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
        <mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
            <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014760</mon:DocumentNumber>
            <mon:ItemNumber>000020</mon:ItemNumber>
        </mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
    </mon:ReturnProperties>
</mon:ReturnsList>
```

XSLT is here [Code](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJV/14)

**O/P from the code( removed unwanted elements)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mon:ReturnsList xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mon="Monsanto:ServiceReturnDetail" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <mon:ReturnProperties>
        <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
        <mon:Status/>
        <mon:Comments/>
        <mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
            <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
            <mon:ItemNumber>000010</mon:ItemNumber>
        </mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
        <mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
            <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
            <mon:ItemNumber>000010</mon:ItemNumber>
        </mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
    </mon:ReturnProperties>
    <mon:ReturnProperties>
        <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
        <mon:Status/>
        <mon:Comments/>
        <mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
            <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
            <mon:ItemNumber>000010</mon:ItemNumber>
        </mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
        <mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
            <mon:DocumentNumber>0020014747</mon:DocumentNumber>
            <mon:ItemNumber>000010</mon:ItemNumber>
        </mon:ReturnDetailResponseDetails>
    </mon:ReturnProperties>
</mon:ReturnsList>
```

can anyone please advise me why I am getting about error?

Comment: I suggest you minimize your example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem, and post all the relevant code here.

Comment: Hi Michael I have edited the question and removed the unwanted code